# How to calculate the size of a UIFont

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am trying to calculate the size of UIFont when change the frame of UITextView.

e.g font size is 14 for frame 0,0,260,320 , so how to get proportional font size for (0,0,1800,1200)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the font size to fit the frame, you just need to set

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```